# Joomla Contact Form not receiving emails

Tags: joomla, contact-form

I have a contact form and it worked well last November. But days after I did an extension update of "JCH optimized" and "sourcerersLab", the contact form isn't working: there is inconsistency, sometimes it sends but sometimes it does not.

I test the extension update first in my test environment site, and no problem occurred. But when I execute the update on the production site, the contact form doesn't send email. It is so difficult to duplicate the error in the test environment, and it didn't get the same error.

I already checked the `Global Configuration >> Mail Settings` are set correctly, and have tried PHP mail, sendmail and SMTP, and they are all working fine.

After I read this article, that stated, "sometimes JCH Optimize extension' stuff breaks without noticing right away, and the possible issues can be the Contact Forms are not working."
Reference Link : https://joomlaseo.com/seo-extensions/jch-optimize

I tried to disable the minify JS and CSS area in the extension of JCH Optimized, but still it didn't work. Also tried to disable the whole plugin and delete the cache, also didn't help.

Other things I noticed that when I turn it to offline:

- the contact form working well. I received the emails on the messages
  sent during site offline.
- there is success and error message displayed.

But when it is returned online:
- the contact form doesn't work again.
- And there is no error message when I send message in contact form, even success message.

I am not sure if there is error that has not been caught or what?

My Joomla version: 3.6.4

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the updates has caused some JavaScript conflicts (maybe updated some libraries, included some additional libraries, etc...).

Do the following: Check the console log in Chrome after visiting the contact us page, and address all the errors there (press Submit on the contact us as this may generate additional errors).